# Verilog select bit depending on input

Tags: verilog

I am writing a behavioral verilog module where a different bit is selected based upon one of the input variables.  I wrote the following code to reference the 3-S position in the D vector:

```
module Part4(input [3:0] D, input [1:0] S, output F);
    always @(D, S)
        F = D[3-S];
endmodule
```

This gives the following errors: "ERROR:HDLCompilers:247 - "Part4.v" line 5 Reference to scalar wire 'F' is not a legal reg or variable lvalue
ERROR:HDLCompilers:44 - "Part4.v" line 5 Illegal left hand side of blocking assignment"

How do I go about selecting a different bit based upon the input S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `F` is a `wire`, then you can't `assign` to it inside an `always @` block. Either change it to a `reg`, or do the assignment outside of an `always @` block like this:

```
module Part4(input [3:0] D, input [1:0] S, output F);
    assign F = D[3-S];
endmodule
```

Comment: Ok thanks!  Out of curiosity how will this circuit be synthesized?  Like is it actually going to create 2 wires somewhere that send the signal for what bit to read or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: Both approaches will result in the same synthesis, since there were no latches in `always @(D, S)`, but changing `F` to a `wire` will result in faster compilation since there's less optimization needed. To answer your question, it's probably just a typical multiplexer that switches on `S`, but if you want to confirm you should look at the synthesis diagram yourself depending on the tools you have.